# How to delete record for multiple table in one query using oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex-5

> For Example I have execute this sql query which is given a result.
>   I want to delete those result using oracle query.

```html
 Select 
a.ENAME    ,
a.JOB,
a.MGR,
a.HIREDATE,
a.SAL,
b.DEPTNO,
b.DNAME,
b.LOC
from emp a , dept b where a.DEPTNO=b.DEPTNO and a.DEPTNO=10
DELETE FROM emp , dept 
WHERE a.DEPTNO=b.DEPTNO
```

Comment: You cannot do it in a Single query.  You would need two query to delete from 2 tables.

Comment: can you explain

Comment: See below answer. Its well explained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not any command to delete from two tables link that. But I propose two scenarios. First scenario can be used for non parent/child tables. Second scenario can be used for parent/child tables.

**First**: Gather all your **common PK's** or any common field of your tables. (Surely you have a common field). like below query:

```
(Select a.DEPTNO from emp a , dept b where a.DEPTNO=b.DEPTNO and a.DEPTNO=10)
```

Then use sequence of delete commands in one transaction.

```
delete from dept where DEPTNO IN (Select a.DEPTNO from emp a , dept b where a.DEPTNO=b.DEPTNO and a.DEPTNO=10)
delete from emp where DEPTNO IN (Select a.DEPTNO from emp a , dept b where a.DEPTNO=b.DEPTNO and a.DEPTNO=10)
```

**Second**: use CASCADE DELETE configuration. (just for parent/child tables) 
This solution is harmful, if side effects could not be controled.
In cascade delete, when a record in the parent table is deleted, then the corresponding records in the child table will automatically be deleted.

Comment: `CASCADE DELETE` works where you have a Foreign Key relationship. And you declare this during the table creation. Read a good rxample here https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php

Comment: thanks, I know that (Second scenario can be used for parent/child tables.)

Comment: @XING . . . The foreign key relation can be defined after the table is created as well.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I know that but i was talking about the cascade on delete. Please read my post above,